# How do I replace all the characters that don't meet this regex string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Since AWS requires a specific regex value of `^([\p{L}\p{Z}\p{N}_.:/=+-@]*)$`for its instance ID for AWS SSM, I am trying to figure out the best way to replace letters in a string if it doesn't match.

For example, if my string is `Test (sample)`, which doesn't meet the above regex, how do I replace the parentheses (since it's a part of the characters that don't match) with a space?

Comment: For readers like me (if any), who didn't know what "AWS" was, it's evidentally [Amazon Web Services](https://searchaws.techtarget.com/definition/Amazon-Web-Services).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String#sub` if `String#match` returns nil:

```
str = 'Test (sample)'
re = %r{^([\p{L}\p{Z}\p{N}_.:/=+-@]*)$}

str = if str.match re
        str
      else
        str.sub(/\(.*\)/, '( )')
      end

str # => "Test ( )"
```

Comment: That's replacing the words in the parentheses though. What needs to be replaced are the parentheses in this example, but more importantly -- anything that doesn't match the regex needs to be replaced.